# Hive self join based on previous date

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have one table with three columns id, name, and date.  Each day I get a dump of all the names and ids from an external process.  I want to produce an output table where for each day I get a count of the unique number of names that occurred on that day that I have not seen before.

For instance, given the following data

```
id    name    d
1    Bob    2014-01-01
2    Suzy   2014-01-01
3    Jen    2014-01-02
4    Jen    2014-01-02
5    Bob    2014-01-02
6    Jon    2014-01-03
7    Mike   2014-01-03
8    Suzy   2014-01-03
```

I want a query to return

```
d             name_count
2014-01-02    1
2014-01-03    2
```

My first thought was to use a correlated subquery like below but Hive doesn't support that

```
select c.d, count(distinct lower(c.name)) as name_count
from db c
where lower(c.name) not in (
  select lower(p.name) as name
  from db p
  where p.d < c.d
  group by lower(p.company_name)
)
group by d
```

I also though about using a left outer join, but I don't think this will give me what I want

```
select c.d, count(distinct lower(c.name)) as name
from db c
left outer join db p on lower(c.name) = lower(p.name)
where p.name is null and p.d < c.d
group by c.d;
```

because p.name will never be null as I'm self joining.

Do you guys know if my second query will work?  If not can you please suggest an alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach but a nested query should solve this:

Query:

> select q.d, COUNT(*) from  (select name, min(d) as d from table_name
>   GROUP BY name)q GROUP BY q.d

Output:

```
2014-01-01  2
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  2
```

Answer (score 0):

The second query won't work, the date compare shall be within the join, as following:

```
select c.date, count(distinct c.name) as count_name
from db c
left join db p 
on lower(c.name) = lower(p.name)
and p.date < c.date
where p.name is null
group by c.date
```

You can test it on http://sqlfiddle.com/ using the below schema:

```
CREATE TABLE db
(
id int,
name varchar(255),
date varchar(20) 
);

insert into db values(1,'Bob', '2014-01-01');
insert into db values(2,'Suzy', '2014-01-01');
insert into db values(3,'Jen', '2014-01-02');
insert into db values(4,'Jen', '2014-01-02');
insert into db values(5,'Bob', '2014-01-02');
insert into db values(6,'Jon', '2014-01-03');
insert into db values(7,'Mike', '2014-01-03');
insert into db values(8,'Suzy', '2014-01-03');
```

Comment: I tried this too and it doesn't work on hive.  I get the following error FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 3:93 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'd'